# Show and keep div visible while action is within div or input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show a div under input field when user click/focus a input field and hide the div when focus is out or User clicks outside the div or input field.
In this fiddle example, when i click input, a div is shown and when i click outside the input field it gets hidden.

But i want to keep the div visible in below conditions :

```
1. When input is focused/clicked.
2. When click is within the div(.options).
```

The div should be hidden when:

```
1. Input is unfocused and click in not within div.
2. Click outside div.
```

[Fiddle URL](https://jsfiddle.net/L81nwp0v/9/)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `relatedTarget` like the following way:

```js
$(function () {
    var inputField = $('#input_field');
    var optionsResult = $('#options');

    inputField.focusin(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        optionsResult.show();
    }).focusout(function (e) {
        if(e.relatedTarget){
          if(e.relatedTarget.tagName != 'A')
            optionsResult.hide();
        }
        else{
          optionsResult.hide();
        }
    });
});

$(document).on('click', function(e){
  if(e.target.tagName == 'HTML'){
    $('#options').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.options{
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #eee;
}
a{
  display:block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="app">
  <div class="header">
    <div id="main_container" class="box">
      <div class="inputs">
        <input id="input_field" type="text" placeholder="Demo account"/>
      </div>
      <div id="options" class="options">
        <a href="#">Common Link</a>
        <a href="#">Common Link 2 </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Data">
  Another Data Set
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its not working perfectly, When you click inside input field and then directly click on any link inside the div. After that wherever you click the div will remain visible. unless you again click in input field and then click body.

Answer (score 2):

make sure the body tag contains your app and it's full width and height of the window. add en event listener to see if the click event is outside of the options div and not the input field. hide the options div if that is the case.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/egnprukh/8/)

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```
$(function () {
    var inputField = $('#input_field');
    var optionsResult = $('#options');
    var options = document.querySelector('#options');

    // Listen for click events on body
    document.body.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      // hide options if click is outside of options div and not the input element
      if (!options.contains(event.target) && event.target.id !== 'input_field') {
        optionsResult.hide();
      }
    });

    inputField.focusin(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        optionsResult.show();
    });
});
```